# 400(Bad Request) when a Json object is posted

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, stringify

I am doing a post request for a wcf service email is my object which is having attributes subject and body.
When I try to make a ajax call I am getting 400 Bad Request error this is my code below. I don't know how to put a object in stringify function.

```
{
  "email": {
     "subject": "b",
     "body": "d"
  }
}

 $('#Button1').click(function() {
            var email = {
                subject: $("#Text1").val(),
                body: $("#Text1").val(),

            }

            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:29143/Restwebservice.svc/sendmail",
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',

                //data: JSON.stringify(email)
                data: JSON.stringify(email),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#target').html(data.msg);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Calling your wcf service directly works though?

Comment: actually iam calling this service in a website

Comment: No, I mean do you get a result if you call http://localhost:29143/Restwebservice.svc/sendmail with Fiddler or a similar tool?

Comment: http://www.getpostman.com/ is good for manual endpoint testing as well.

Comment: how does your `sendmail` method signature looks like?post that.

Comment: [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST",
            BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "sendmail",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool SendMail(Email email);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown us `sendmail` method,however I assume from the data structure of ajax call it should look like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class EmailEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string subject { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

Now the `sendmail` method would look like this

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public void sendmail(EmailEntity emailentity)
{
  ............
}
```

Note that request type is wrapped so while posting data from ajax you would ideally create a `emailentity` object first which would work as wrapper object.

```
var emailentity = {};
emailentity.subject = "Test subject";
emailentity.body = "Test body";

var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(emailentity);
var dataToSend = '{"emailentity":'+jsonObj+'}';
```

this `dataToSend` will be posted now via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: dataToSend,
            url: "../path/myService.svc/sendmail",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",          
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bad request occurs when the json is invalid, here this error is because you have an Object there called "email", and then on Button1 click you are defining new variable called 'email'. Here instead of referring to the previous email object you are creating new variable and trying to assign values to its members when there is no member for "var email". try doing something like this

```
Object email = new Object();
email.subject =$("#Text1").val();
email.body = $("#Text1").val();
```

And now stringify this 'email' object, but make sure that at server side you receive the same object as email, because if sending and receiving objects doesn't match it throws bad request.